# Why is $S^1 \times S^1=$ Torus and $S^2 \ne S^1 \times S^1$

Tags: general-topology, product-space

I understand that topologically a Torus, $S^1 \times S^1$ is very different from a 2-Sphere, $S^2$.

My question is more specifically aimed at understand the meaning of $\times$ that is use $S^1 \times S^1$.

1. What is this $\times$ called in mathematics and what are its properties?

I am familiar with Cartesian Product as in $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, which is just a tuple in coordinate representation (which is what I understand). But the above encounters seems to suggest that my understanding is incorrect/ partial.

2. So, what exactly am I missing?

Comment: $\mathbb R^{2n}$ is topologically the same as $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$. It's not clear what you are trying to say in that paragraph.

Comment: @ArcticChar I have no idea what it means so I can't provide anymore details, nevertheless I have added the source, which states that. Also I will look through Wikipedia's Symplectic Geometry to see if I can find anything relevant

Comment: $S^2$ turns out to be the _smash product_ $S^1\wedge S^1$. But that's another story.

Comment: The notation $A\times B$ always denotes some kind of [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(mathematics)#Products_over_other_algebraic_structures). When $A$ and $B$ are sets with some additional structure, this is usually the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) as sets which then gets equipped with the same structure as $A$ and $B$. For example a product of groups is the Cartesian product of the underlying sets equipped with the structure of a group that is given by the group structures of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Do you want me to post that paragraph in Physics SE, to get more details on that?

Comment: I think this is just a misunderstanding of what the source is actually saying. They're talking about how the phase space is not always $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, not that the product is not always $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

Comment: From the paragraph it is said that when the motion is unconstrained, that is, when the particular are free to move in $\mathbb R^n$, then the phase space is $\mathbb R^{2n}$. Sometimes when the particular is constrained to stay in a manifold $M$, the phase space is $T^*M$ the cotangent bundle of $M$.

Comment: They give an example of the pendulum: the particule stays in $\mathbb S^1$, so the phase space is $T^*\mathbb S^1 = \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb R$, the cylinder.

Comment: Oh okay thank you... @ArcticChar I read it wrong sorry. I will remove that right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abstractly, the product $\times$ for topological spaces is defined as follows:

> Given two topological spaces $X,Y$ the product $X\times Y$ is the unique space (up to unique homeomorphism) such that
>
> 1. There are two continuous functions $p_1:X\times Y\to X$ and $p_2:X\times Y\to Y$
> 2. For any space $Z$ with continuous functions $f_1:Z\to X$ and $f_2:Z\to Y$, there is a unique continuous function $f:Z\to X\times Y$ such that $f_i=p_i\circ f$ for each $i$

This definition carries over to other categories too, like sets (swap "continuous function" with "function"), groups (swap "continuous function" with "homomorphism"), vector spaces (swap "continuous function" with "linear transformation"), and so on. That's the beauty of abstract definitions. The downside is that it is, well, abstract. That kind of definition takes some real work to get used to.

However, we can also construct the product more concretely. The topological space $X\times Y$ has the set of all pairs $\{(x,y)\mid x\in X, y\in Y\}$ as its points. The topology is given by a basis of "rectangles"; any set of the form $U\times V=\{(u,v)\mid u\in U, v\in V\}$ where $U\subseteq X$ and $V\subseteq Y$ are open (we can also restrict ourselves to $U,V$ being elements of some basis for the topologies of $X$ and $Y$ rather than general open sets) (these sets are in fact actual rectangles in the case of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$ when $U,V$ are open intervals).

This is a construction you have to use a few times to get used to, but it's nowhere as tough as the abstract definition. Many other categories, like the ones mentioned above, use the same base set for their product. Then in a similar fashion to how we constructed the topology on the product, they build the relevant structure on top of this set. The category of sets is the simplest example, where there is no additional structure, you just have the set of pairs, and that's it.

For later, it could be worth noting that the abstract definition (suitably generalized) is a big contributor to why a product of infinitely many spaces doesn't have the topology you might intuitively expect the first time you encounter it.

Comment: Tell me if I am right. So the difference between $S^1 \times S^1$ and $S^2$, is that although I could find a set of ordered pairs , $\{(x,y)\mid x\in S^1, y\in S^1\}$, but I cannot find a topology on this set that is homeomorphic to $S^2$?

Comment: The second part is right, but I don't see why the first part seems to imply otherwise. The torus $S^1\times S^1$ is not in any obvious way equal to $S^2$ as a set.

Comment: @ElliotG Okay thanks. Its obvious when I picture the two structure, as in one has a hole right through the middle, while other has a hole inside, the surface being intact. I was thinking in terms of how to make these suing $S^1$s as in both are made of some combination of circles. Torus has a primary circle, with each point on it having a secondary circle. $S^2$ also has this feature, but this time the secondary circles touches the primary at two points, instead of one.

Comment: @TheImperfectCrazy They have the same number of points, so you could always find _some_ topology on the set $S^1\times S^1$ that makes it homeomorphic to $S^2$ with standard topology (fix a bijection and declare it to be a homeomorphism, that will give you a topology). But it won't be pretty, and it won't in any way "inherit" its topology from that of $S^1$ the way the product topology does.

Comment: @Arthur Just to be clear do you mean that I can find a Homeomorphism from the PROPER SUBSET of $S^1 \times S^1$ to $S^2$? I mean if I would find a homeomorphism from the whole of $S^1 \times S^1$ to $S^2$, then wouldn't that make both of them essentially the same.

Comment: @TheImperfectCrazy What I'm saying is that you can construct a topology (an **ugly** topology) on $S^1\times S^1$ to make it homeomorphic to $S^2$. With the standard topologies, neither is homeomorphic to a subset of the other (proper or not). However, there are plenty of proper subsets (even _open_ proper subsets) of $S^1\times S^1$ that are homeomorphic to (open) proper subsets of $S^2$.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense... Thank you for your time! I actually found both torus and 2-Sphere quite similar as in made of circles, and I found it strange when Physicists say they are never the same.

Answer (score 2):

The cartesian product is a set-theoretic operation. You can take two sets and form their cartesian product. However, when we talk about the cartesian product of some richer structures, like topological spaces, we mean that the set-theoretic cartesian product has been endowed with a natural structure. For example, when we have two topological spaces, one can define the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) on their cartesian product which forms the product space. The writing $S^1\times S^1$ refers to this operation.

To see that $S^1\times S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $S^2$, the easiest thing to do is find a topological property of the one that is not enjoyed by the other. I can't think of something very elementary besides the fact that $S^2$ is simply connected and $S^1\times S^1$ is not: every loop (i.e. continuous path with the same endpoints) on $S^2$ can be continuously deformed to a single point. This is not true for $S^1\times S^1$.

Comment: @ElliotG Yes, of course, I messed the terminology, thanks for clarifying

Comment: Thank you for your time. I didn't know that $\times$ can also have an implicit inherited natural topological structure.

Comment: @TheImperfectCrazy No problem. Not only that, but the same is true for many algebraic structures: cartesian product of vector spaces, groups, rings, etc

Answer (score 1):

We can view $S^1$ as subset of $\Bbb R^2$ in a standard way:
$$S^1=\{\,(x_1,x_2)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x_1^2+x_2^2=1\,\}. $$
This allows us to find $S^1\times S^1$ also in a standard way inside $\Bbb R^4$ (or more precisely: $\Bbb R^2\times \Bbb R^2$, but that's "the same") as
$$S^1\times S^1=\{\,(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\Bbb R^4\mid x_1^2+x_2^2=1\land x_3^2+x_4^2=1\,\}. $$
This is very different from
$$S^2=\{\,(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1\,\} $$
(as well as from
$S^3=\{\,(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\Bbb R^3\mid x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1\,\} $
).

Comment: Interesting... this is the smash product that @Arthur mentioned in the comment. Just a curious follow-up question: Does this mean that $S^1 \times S^1$ requires atleast $\mathbb{R}^4$ to be embedded while $S^2$ just requires $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @TheImperfectCrazy $S^1\times S^1$ can be embedded in $\Bbb R^3$; it's just a hollow donut.